# Are lord Ganpati and lord maha ganpati the same or different

Tags: ganesha

As per my knowledge lord Ganesh is son of Lord Shivshankar Sambhu and mata Parvati. I asked my question to a Pandit Ji near me, He suggested me that, there are two Ganapati so both are different and lord Maha Ganpati is known as Pratham Pujya.

Please clearly my below questions

1. Are both Ganapati and Maha Ganpati the same or different? If different please describe about their birth.
2. Who is Pratham Pujya? Ganapati or Maha Ganpati?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kindly check [this](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/2021/03/26/mahaganapati-murti-vaibhava/) out Sir.Also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-two_forms_of_Ganesha) wiki page along with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahaganapati#cite_note-7) may provide some useful insights. Hope this helps!

Comment: Earlier i had asked many questions here and got answer for them too. So i have a hope that someone might answer this also. Thank you 

Comment: I think that the paṇḍita who told you this must be a Gāṇapatya, because this statement of his is based on Gāṇapatya texts like the Gaṇeśa purāṇa & Mudgala purāṇa. There Mahāgaṇapati is described as the direct manifested form of the Niṛguṇa Brahman, who then proceeds to create the Tridevas & Gaṇapati as the avatāra of the primordial Mahāgaṇapati, who incarnated as the son of Pārvatī, due to her observance of a certain vrata desiring progeny. But non-Gāṇapatyas don't believe in the pre-existence of Gaṇapati's any manifestation before that of his being born as the son of Pārvatī.

Comment: For them, Mahāgaṇapati is verily another form of Gaṇapati, the son of Pārvatī. And to differentiate between is completely absurd.